# Swift3 スワイプで切替えるカレンダーでCollectionViewCellの選択をうまく解除できない

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

下記の2ページを参考にスワイプで切替えるカレンダーを作成したのですが、CollectionViewCellの選択をうまく解除できません。
http://qiita.com/kitanoow/items/65b1418527eabf31e45b
http://qiita.com/sakuran/items/3c2c9f22cbcbf4aff731

**実装したいこと**
カレンダーの内容として以下のものを実装したいです。

1. 左右にスワイプで月ごとのカレンダーを切替える
2. 日付をタップしたセルの背景に予め用意した画像を表示
3. 同月内の日付をタップしたら過去に選択したセルの画像表示を解除
4. 他の月に移動して日付をタップしたら過去に選択した他月のセルの画像表示を解除

**解決したい問題**
上記の1から3まではなんとか動かせるようになったのですが、問題なのは4番の1画面進んで1画面戻った場合の下記のような挙動です。

こんなイメージで、スワイプしたら画面が左右にスクロールするものです。
[前の月] [現在の月] [次の月]

[現在の月]セルを選択
セルの背景画像を表示
↓
[次の月]に1画面移動
セルを選択→セルの背景画像を表示
↓
先程の[現在の月]に1画面戻る
選択したセルの背景が解除されていない

[現在の月]→[次の月]→[次の月]と2画面移動した後に戻る場合には選択が解除されています。
1画面進んで、1画面戻る場合には既に生成されたCollectionViewがうまく更新できていないからだとは思うのですが、どのようにすれば解決できるのか分かりません。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
以下はソースコードです。

```
// AppDelegat.swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var scheduleAt : Date?
    var eventType = 1

    var selCalDayID : Int?
}
```

---

```
// ViewController.swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let calView = CalendarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 290))
        self.view.addSubview(calView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
// CalendarView.swift
class CalendarView : UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    var currentYear:Int = 0
    var currentMonth:Int = 0
    var currentDay:Int = 0

    let daysPerWeek: Int = 7
    var currentDate = Date()
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var currentMonthView : CalCollectionView!
    var nextMonthView : CalCollectionView!
    var prevMonthView : CalCollectionView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var getNextMonth:Date!
    var getPrevMonth:Date!

    override init(frame:CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let screenWidth : CGFloat = frame.size.width
        let screenHeight : CGFloat = 290

        // まずはscrollviewを追加
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.bounds)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width *  3.0,height: frame.size.height)
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: screenWidth , y: 0.0)
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

        self.addSubview(scrollView)

        let cal = Calendar.current

        if appDelegate.eventType != 0 {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-DD"
            appDelegate.scheduleAt = formatter.date(from: "2017-01-31")!
            currentDate = appDelegate.scheduleAt!
        }

        getNextMonth = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: cal.startOfDay(for: currentDate))
        getPrevMonth = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: cal.startOfDay(for: currentDate))

        currentMonthView = CalCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: screenWidth, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight), selDate: currentDate)

        nextMonthView = CalCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: screenWidth * 2, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight), selDate: getNextMonth!)

        prevMonthView = CalCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight), selDate: getPrevMonth!)

        scrollView.addSubview(currentMonthView)
        scrollView.addSubview(nextMonthView)
        scrollView.addSubview(prevMonthView)

    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView:UIScrollView) {

        let pos:CGFloat  = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width

        let deff:CGFloat = pos - 1.0
        if fabs(deff) >= 1.0 {
            if (deff > 0) {
                self.showNextView()
            } else {
                self.showPrevView()
            }
        }
    }

    func showNextView (){
        currentMonth += 1
        if( currentMonth > 12 ){
            currentMonth = 1
            currentYear += 1
        }

        let tmpView = currentMonthView
        currentMonthView = nextMonthView
        nextMonthView    = prevMonthView
        prevMonthView    = tmpView

        let nextYearAndMonth = self.getNextYearAndMonth()
        nextMonthView.setUpDays(nextYearAndMonth)

        self.resetContentOffSet()
    }

    func showPrevView () {
        currentMonth -= 1
        if( currentMonth == 0 ){
            currentMonth = 12
            currentYear -= 1
        }

        let tmpView = currentMonthView
        currentMonthView = prevMonthView
        prevMonthView    = nextMonthView
        nextMonthView    = tmpView

        let prevYearAndMonth = self.getPrevYearAndMonth()
        prevMonthView.setUpDays(prevYearAndMonth)

        //position調整
        self.resetContentOffSet()
    }

    func resetContentOffSet () {
        //position調整
        prevMonthView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width,height: frame.size.height)
        currentMonthView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width, y: 0, width: frame.size.width,height: frame.size.height)
        nextMonthView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width * 2.0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width,height: frame.size.height)

        let scrollViewDelegate:UIScrollViewDelegate = scrollView.delegate!
        scrollView.delegate = nil
        //delegateを呼びたくないので
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width , y: 0.0)
        scrollView.delegate = scrollViewDelegate
    }

    func getNextYearAndMonth () -> Date {
        var next_year:Int = currentYear
        var next_month:Int = currentMonth + 1
        if next_month > 12 {
            next_month = 1
            next_year += 1
        }

        let cal = Calendar.current
        let increaseYear = cal.date(byAdding: .year, value: next_year, to: cal.startOfDay(for: currentDate))
        let increaseMonth = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: next_month, to: cal.startOfDay(for: increaseYear!))

        return increaseMonth!
    }

    func getPrevYearAndMonth () -> Date {
        var prev_year:Int = currentYear
        var prev_month:Int = currentMonth - 1
        if prev_month == 0 {
            prev_month = 12
            prev_year -= 1
        }

        let cal = Calendar.current
        let decreaseYear = cal.date(byAdding: .year, value: prev_year, to: cal.startOfDay(for: currentDate))
        let decreaseMonth = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: prev_month, to: cal.startOfDay(for: decreaseYear!))

        return decreaseMonth!
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
// CalCollectionView.swift
class CalCollectionView : UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let calMng = CalendarManager()
    var collectionView : UICollectionView!
    var cellSize: CGFloat = 0.0
    let cellMargin: CGFloat = 0
    let weekArray = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, selDate: Date){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setUpDays(selDate)
    }

    func setUpDays(_ selDate: Date){
        calMng.currentMonthOfDates = []
        calMng.currentDate = selDate

        let screenWidth : CGFloat = frame.size.width
        let screenHeight : CGFloat = 290

        // CollectionViewのレイアウトを生成.
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        // Cell一つ一つの大きさ.
        cellSize = frame.size.width / 7
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: 40)

        // CollectionViewを生成.
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: screenWidth, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(screenHeight)), collectionViewLayout: layout)

        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

        collectionView.center = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)

        // Cellに使われるクラスを登録.
        collectionView.register(CalCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "calCell")

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        collectionView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        self.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    // セクションの数
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    // Cellの総数を返す
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Section毎にCellの総数を変える.
        if section == 0 {
            return 7
        } else {
            return calMng.daysAcquisition()
        }
    }

    // セルの内容を表示
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: CalCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "calCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CalCollectionCell

        if indexPath.row % 7 == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightRed()
        } else if indexPath.row % 7 == 6 {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightBlue()
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        }

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = weekArray[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            let day = calMng.conversionDateFormat(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            let ordinalityDay = calMng.ordinalityDay() - 2
            // 月の日数
            let daysOfMonth = calMng.daysOfMonth()
            let lastRow = ordinalityDay + daysOfMonth



            if indexPath.row > ordinalityDay {
                // 現在のセルアイテムの日付を取得
                let itemDay = calMng.currentMonthOfDates[indexPath.row]
                // イベント予定日と同じかどうかをチェック
                let isSelectedDay = calMng.compareDate(selDate: itemDay)
                if isSelectedDay == true {
                    appDelegate.selCalDayID = indexPath.row
                    cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "cal-bg")
                    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
                    cell.textLabel?.text = day
                } else {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = day
                    cell.imgView.image = UIImage()
                }
            } else {
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                cell.textLabel?.text = nil
            }

            if indexPath.row > lastRow {
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                cell.textLabel?.text = nil
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    //セルの垂直方向のマージンを設定
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellMargin
    }

    //セルの水平方向のマージンを設定
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellMargin
    }

    // セルをタップした時の処理
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            // タップしたセルアイテムの日付を取得
            let selItemDay = calMng.currentMonthOfDates[indexPath.row]
            // イベント予定日と同じかどうかをチェック
            let isSelectedDate = calMng.compareDate(selDate: selItemDay)

            if isSelectedDate == false {
                // 現状の選択したIDを一旦保持
                let tmpItemID = appDelegate.selCalDayID
                // 選択したIDを新規にセット
                appDelegate.selCalDayID = indexPath.row
                // 日付の内容を変更
                appDelegate.scheduleAt = calMng.currentMonthOfDates[indexPath.row]
                // 古いセルをリロード
                reloadItem(selItem: tmpItemID!)
                // 新しいセルをリロード
                reloadItem(selItem: appDelegate.selCalDayID!)
            }
        }
    }

    func reloadItem(selItem: Int) {
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: selItem, section: 1)])
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    class func lightBlue() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 50.0 / 255, green: 149.0 / 255, blue: 218.0 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    class func lightRed() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 222.0 / 255, green: 32 / 255, blue: 63 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
// CalCollectionCell.swift
class CalCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var textLabel : UILabel?
    var imgView : UIImageView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // UILabelを生成.
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
        textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34))
        imgView.center = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        // Cellに追加.
        self.contentView.addSubview(imgView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(textLabel!)
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
// CalendarManager.swift
class CalendarManager {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    //表記する月の配列
    var currentMonthOfDates = [Date]()
    // カレンダー表示用
    var currentDate = Date()
    let daysPerWeek: Int = 7
    var numberOfItems: Int!

    var cal = Calendar.current

    //月ごとのセルの数を返すメソッド
    func daysAcquisition() -> Int {
        // 週の数
        let numOfWeeks = Calendar.current.range(of: .weekOfMonth, in: .month, for: firstDateOfMonth())!.count
        // 週の数 x 列の数
        numberOfItems = numOfWeeks * daysPerWeek
        return numberOfItems
    }

    //月の初日を取得
    func firstDateOfMonth() -> Date {
        var components = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from:currentDate)
        components.day = 1
        let firstDateMonth = cal.date(from: components)!

        return firstDateMonth
    }

    //  月の初日が週の何日目かを計算
    func ordinalityDay() -> Int {
        let ordinalityDay = cal.ordinality(of: .day, in: .weekOfMonth, for: firstDateOfMonth())!

        return ordinalityDay
    }

    // 月の日数
    func daysOfMonth() -> Int {
        let year = cal.component(.year, from: currentDate)
        let month = cal.component(.month, from: currentDate)

        let date = cal.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month))!
        // 日数
        let days = cal.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date)?.count

        return days!
    }

    // ⑴表記する日にちの取得
    func dateForCellAtIndexPath(numberOfItems: Int) {
        // ①「月の初日が週の何日目か」を計算する
        let ordinalityOfFirstDay = cal.ordinality(of: .day, in: .weekOfMonth, for: firstDateOfMonth())

        for i in 0 ..< numberOfItems {
            // ②「月の初日」と「indexPath.item番目のセルに表示する日」の差を計算する
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.day = i - (ordinalityOfFirstDay! - 1)

            // ③ 表示する月の初日から②で計算した差を引いた日付を取得
            let date = cal.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: firstDateOfMonth())!

            // ④配列に追加
            currentMonthOfDates.append(date)
        }
    }

    // ⑵表記の変更
    func conversionDateFormat(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String {
        dateForCellAtIndexPath(numberOfItems: numberOfItems)
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d"

        return formatter.string(from: currentMonthOfDates[indexPath.row])
    }

    func compareDate(selDate: Date) -> Bool {
        let isSameDay = cal.isDate(appDelegate.scheduleAt!, inSameDayAs: selDate)

        return isSameDay
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あなたのコードの中で、日付のタップを処理しているのは`CalCollectionView.(_:didSelectItemAt:)`中のこの部分ですね。

```
        if isSelectedDate == false {
            // 現状の選択したIDを一旦保持
            let tmpItemID = appDelegate.selCalDayID
            // 選択したIDを新規にセット
            appDelegate.selCalDayID = indexPath.row
            // 日付の内容を変更
            appDelegate.scheduleAt = calMng.currentMonthOfDates[indexPath.row]
            // 古いセルをリロード
            reloadItem(selItem: tmpItemID!)
            // 新しいセルをリロード
            reloadItem(selItem: appDelegate.selCalDayID!)
        }
```

`appDelegate.selCalDayID = indexPath.row`という行からみて、選択した日付を表す情報としては、単に`indexPath.row`を保存しているだけで、 **それがどの`UICollectionView`の`indexPath.row`なのかを保存していません** 。

上記のコード中で`reloadItem(selItem: tmpItemID!)`の中身は単に現在の月を表す`UICollectionView`中のセルをリロードしているだけですが、日付が前月を表しているのなら`tmpItemID`も前月用の`UICollectionView`中のセルをリロードしないといけないはずです。

---

と言うわけで、まずは「選択されている日付」がどの`UICollectionView`の中に存在するのかの情報もどこかに保存しておかないといけません。

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var scheduleAt : Date?
    var eventType = 1

    var selCalDayID : Int?
    var selCalView: CalCollectionView? //<-
}
```

その上で選択日を保存するところ、保存された選択日を利用するところは適切に書き換えてやらないといけません。上記の部分はこんな感じになるでしょうか。

```
        if !isSelectedDate {
            // 現状の選択したIDを一旦保持
            let tmpItemID = appDelegate.selCalDayID
            let oldSelCalView = appDelegate.selCalView //<-
            // 選択したIDを新規にセット
            appDelegate.selCalDayID = indexPath.row
            appDelegate.selCalView = self //<-
            // 日付の内容を変更
            appDelegate.scheduleAt = calMng.currentMonthOfDates[indexPath.row]
            // 古いセルをリロード
            if let oldItem = tmpItemID, let oldCollectionView = oldSelCalView?.collectionView {
                oldCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: oldItem, section: 1)])
            }
            // 新しいセルをリロード
            reloadItem(selItem: appDelegate.selCalDayID!)
        }
```

(`Bool`値を`true`,`false`と比較するなんていうのはあまりにもダサいので書き換えさせていただきました。(`a > 0`なんて判定を`(a > 0) == true`なんて書いていたら変だと思いませんか?)また、今のあなたのコードでは「選択日がない」という状態は作らないようにしているようですが、それだと`selCalDayID`を`Int?`とOptionalにしている意味もないので、`if-let`を入れています。)

他にも`selCalDayID`を更新している部分があれば、同じようにしないといけないでしょう。

`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`の中:

```
            if isSelectedDay {
                appDelegate.selCalDayID = indexPath.row
                appDelegate.selCalView = self //<-
                cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "cal-bg")
                cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
                cell.textLabel?.text = day
            } else {
                cell.textLabel?.text = day
                cell.imgView.image = nil //<- `UIImage()`は動作が未定義で何が起きるかわからない
            }
```

---

ちなみに***2画面移動した後に戻る場合には選択が解除されています*** の理由は、あなたの`CalendarView`では`nextMonthView`と`prevMonthView`に前月と次月だけの`CalCollectionView`を先読みしているので、2ヶ月分移動させることによって確実に`CalCollectionView`の再作成が行われるためです。

Comment: ご指摘の通り確かに UICollectionView を保持していないですよね。

boolの判定、お恥ずかしながらその通りです。

ご指摘頂いた内容で無事に動作することができました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。「boolの判定」については、「主観であること丸出し」の表現にしたつもりなので、あまり深くは気にしないでください。致命的ではありませんし、日本の技術者の間では私の方が少数派かもしれません。短くコメントにしただけですが、「`UIImage()`は動作が未定義で何が起きるかわからない」の方は少し気にして、 **Cocoa, Cocoa Touchのクラスの多くで`()`を引数とするイニシャライザは動作が未定義であり、クラスによっては致命的な結果をもたらすこともある** と言うのは覚えておいてください。

Comment: bool判定は、ご指摘頂いた書き方の方がスマートな書き方だと思います。むしろ、ご指摘頂いたことが有難いです。UIImage() についても、ご教授頂いていなかったら分からないまま使っていたかと思います。最近やっとプログラムについて少しずつ理解できるようになったのですが、まだまだなんとなくでやっている感があるのは否めません。さらに精進していきたいところです。ありがとうございます。

Comment: あれから色々とブラッシュアップして他のアプリに組み込んでみたのですが、時折、カレンダーをスクロールした後にセルをタップしてリロードしようとする瞬間に `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 31 from section 0 which only contains 30 items before the update'` というエラーが出てクラッシュしてしまうことがあります。何かアドバイス頂けますと助かります。よろしくお願いします

Comment: @marc さん、 現象が再現できるコードがないと確実なことは言えないのですが、「30個しか項目のないsection0で31個目の項目をdeleteしようとしている」と言うエラーですから、何か心当たりはないでしょうか。例えば、`collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)`は30を返すのに31個目を示す`indexPath`で何かの操作(`delete`は内部操作の可能性があるのでコード上は`delete`以外かもしれません)をしているという感じです。その辺りを調べてみて(Xcodeのデバッグ機能は活用できているでしょうか)解決できないようであれば、再現可能なコードを掲載した上で別質問にしていただいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: まさにおっしゃる通り numberOfItemsInSection でのindexPathの処理を変えていたためでした。月末以降のセルは使わないように変更してたために動的にセルの総数が変わってたのを固定数にしたら解決できました。